# Having trouble understanding relational database

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I am trying to build a database of tables, to essentially manage a collection of recipes like a cook book. My wife and I constantly lose the paper recipes. I am trying to design the scheme and don't fully understand the concept. I have a table for recipes, steps, and recipe ingredients (which contains tables   ingredients (which contains tables quantity and measurement type,)

Am I doing it right? My goal is to have the recipe ingredients table contain the information such as 1 pound of hamburger, 3 cups of milk ext....

So do I add the foreign key of measurements and quantity to ingredients only .... to recipe ingredients only or both.

When adding the foreign key to ingredients do the other tables relatively become apart of the ingredients table so any reference to ingredients table will also reference the quantity and measurement tables?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could design your schema like below,

> Recipe(id number, name text, category text, description text);
>
> Ingredients (id number, name text, unit text);
>
> Recipe_Ingrediants(recipe_id number, ingredients_id number, quantity number);

Or if you want to generalize the units for ingredients then you can make a separate table for unit as well, like below,

> Recipe(id number, name text, category text, description text);
>
> Unit(id number, name text, unit text);
>
> Ingredients (id number, name text, unit_id number);
>
> Recipe_Ingrediants(recipe_id number, ingredients_id number, quantity number);

If you want to associate more than one unit for same ingrediants (10 grams sugar and 2 teaspoon sugar), you have to move unit to Recipe_Ingrediants as below,

> Recipe(id number, name text, category text, description text);
>
> Ingredients (id number, name text);
>
> Recipe_Ingrediants(recipe_id number, ingredients_id number, unit text, quantity number);

For more generic solution,

> Recipe(id number, name text, category text, description text);
>
> Unit(id number, name text, unit text);
>
> Ingredients (id number, name text);
>
> Recipe_Ingrediants(recipe_id number, ingredients_id number, unit_id number, quantity number);

Comment: I want to be able to over time in an app save the ingredients and build a list. so If I need 2  1 Pounds of Hamburger. I can output 2 Pounds of Hamburger. Is that possible off the first example or would you have to use the second

Comment: Yes, its possible with first example as well.

Comment: you can make multiple entries in Recipe_Ingrediants for same recipe and ingredients as per requirement.

But problem with this approach is that you can associate only one unit with  any ingrediant.

Comment: I selected your response as the correct anwser could you help explain why the quanity goes in the combined table of recipies and ingredients?

Comment: so  if I had a pound of hamburger and a cup of milk I could only do units of  pounds for both hamb. and milk correct? if that is the case then I would prefer the second example

Comment: No, suppose somewhere you want to add 10 grams of sugar but at some other place you want to add 2 teaspoons of sugar

Comment: Ok I understand that now, now in Unit(id number, name text, unit text);  why a name text, and unit, text wouldnt you just have a name text and load it with things like pound, cup, tablespoon, grams

Comment: yes, you can. Actually I putted name and unit separately because at UI we may want to show only short name of unit, and want to keep complete unit name for reference.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you have Quantity in with Recipe_Ingredients and not separate or with Ingredients

Comment: For each recipe there will be specific quantity of different ingrediants.